# How can I automate starting an instance of my Quarkus service for Endpoint Tests?

Tags: testing, quarkus, rest-assured

I have several Quarkus microservices which I have written many unit tests for. The unit tests call JAX-RS annotated methods directly, verifying that the endpoint Java code functions appropriately and returns the expected output.

I want some additional tests to verify that the correct annotations have been added to these methods and that JAX-RS filters and HTTP auth mechanisms work as expected. The unit tests tell me that if the endpoint is called, the code will work, but I want additional assurance that requests over HTTP receive responses matching my expectations. To do this, I had started writing tests using restassured, however in order to use restassured an instance of my Quarkus application needs to be running and simply running tests does not cause an instance to run in the background. What I end up doing is starting the service manually in my IDE and then in the terminal of the IDE I run these tests that utilize HTTP requests and responses.

I realize this is an opinion based question but I think there is value in hearing what others are doing or what the official docs recommend. Is there an easier/less manual/recommended way to achieve this? Do the Quarkus docs offer a recommendation for this? I want to ensure that the application responds to HTTP requests appropriately prior to building a container image and attempting a deployment to K8s.

Comment: `@QuarkusTest` starts the Quarkus application, so I must be missing something in the description

Comment: @geoand I thought that was the case too but if I just run mvn test, the restassured tests always fail because the service doesn't run. I have several projects in a mono-repo and each behave that way, I am wondering if something is just wrong with my maven plugin configuration in my root pom.xml file.

I'm going to create a minimal project and try mvn test to see if restassured tests run successfully when I execute mvn test.

Comment: @geoand I did find the instructions in the docs for integration tests, so now I am also attempting to migrate my restassured tests into integration test classes and I have set skipITs to false. This seems promising and at least runs the restassured tests during my build phase but I'm having problems there as well. The DockerClientProviderStrategy class from TestContainers is having a hard time working with Docker Desktop on Windows.